# How do I do a regex search in Nokogiri for text that matches a certain beginning?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, hpricot

Given:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
value = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
"<html>
<body>
  <p id='para-1'>A</p>
  <div class='block' id='X1'>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <p id='para-2'>B</p>
  </div>
  <p id='para-3'>C</p>
  <h2>Bar</h2>
  <p id='para-4'>D</p>
  <p id='para-5'>E</p>
  <div class='block' id='X2'>
    <p id='para-6'>F</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>"
HTML_END
```

I want to do something like what I can do in Hpricot:

```
divs = value.search('//div[@id^="para-"]')
```

1. How do I do a pattern search for elements in XPath style?
2. Where would I find the documentation to help me?  I didn't see this in the rdocs.

Comment: PSA: For those attempting more complex regex, this is likely what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649963/nokogiri-searching-for-div-using-xpath

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the xpath function `starts-with`:

```
value.xpath('//p[starts-with(@id, "para-")]').each { |x| puts x['id'] }
```

Comment: Wow, Aaron himself just answered it!

Comment: Author of Nokogiri and RoR core team member.

Answer (score 19):

```
divs = value.css('div[id^="para-"]')
```

Comment: this is a life saver

Answer (score 3):

And some docs you're seeking:

- Nokogiri: http://nokogiri.org/
- XPath: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/
- CSS3 Selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

```
Nokogiri::XML::Node.send(:define_method, 'xpath_regex') { |*args|
  xpath = args[0]
  rgxp = /\/([a-z]+)\[@([a-z\-]+)~=\/(.*?)\/\]/
  xpath.gsub!(rgxp) { |s| m = s.match(rgxp); "/#{m[1]}[regex(.,'#{m[2]}','#{m[3]}')]" }
  self.xpath(xpath, Class.new {
    def regex node_set, attr, regex
      node_set.find_all { |node| node[attr] =~ /#{regex}/ }
    end
  }.new)
}
```

Usage:

```
divs = Nokogiri::HTML(page.root.to_html).
  xpath_regex("//div[@class~=/axtarget$/]//div[@class~=/^carbo/]")
```