# Find elements with names matching a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I am trying to get some nodes from the the below xml.

```
<SalesStart Value="1412899200">10.10.2014</SalesStart>
<SalesEnd Value="4102358400">31.12.2099</SalesEnd>
<Price Value="4.9900">4,99</Price>
<SalesStartEst Value="1411516800">24.09.2014</SalesStartEst>
<SalesEndEst Value="1697500800">17.10.2023</SalesEndEst>
```

I can access nodes like `doc.text_at('SalesStart')`. Is it possible to access nodes with regular expression something like

```
doc.text_at('Sales'[/Start/]) or doc.css('Sales'[/Start/])
```

so that i can get 2 nodes**(SalesStart and SalesStartEst)** in a single query??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556028/how-do-i-do-a-regex-search-in-nokogiri

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a title match, but not a good duplicate. It shows how to find attributes whose value matches a pattern; this question is about elements whose name matches a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot use a generic regular expression in Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405507/405017) itself—since it leans on libxml2 which only supports XPath 1.0—but in your case you just want elements whose name starts with `SalesStart`. That is possible in XPath 1.0 using the `starts-with()` function:

```
# Find all elements, ensuring the correct prefix on the name
doc.xpath("//*[starts-with(name(),'SalesStart')]")
```

Demo:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML '
  <r>
    <SalesStart Value="1412899200">10.10.2014</SalesStart>
    <SalesEnd Value="4102358400">31.12.2099</SalesEnd>
    <Price Value="4.9900">4,99</Price>
    <SalesStartEst Value="1411516800">24.09.2014</SalesStartEst>
    <SalesEndEst Value="1697500800">17.10.2023</SalesEndEst>
  </r>
'

starts = doc.xpath("//*[starts-with(name(),'SalesStart')]").map(&:text)
p starts #=> ["10.10.2014", "24.09.2014"]
```

---

However, if you did **need** a regular expression, then you can over-find the elements using Nokogiri and then use Ruby to pare down the set. For example:

```
# memory-heavy approach; pulls all elements and then pares them down
starts = doc.xpath('//*').select{ |e| e.name =~ /^SalesStart/ }

# lightweight approach, accessing one node at a time
starts = []
doc.traverse do |node|
  starts<<node if node.element? && node.name =~ /^SalesStart/
end
p starts.map(&:text) #=> ["10.10.2014", "24.09.2014"]
```

You can even wrap this up as a convenience method:

```
# monkeypatching time!
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def elements_with_name_matching( regex )
    [].tap{ |result| traverse{ |n| result<<n if n.element? && n.name=~regex } }
  end
end

p doc.elements_with_name_matching( /^SalesStart/ ).map(&:text)
#=> ["10.10.2014", "24.09.2014"]
```