# How can I escape quotes in a custom css pseudo class argument in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I was trying to define a custom CSS pseudo class in Nokogiri and ran into some issues with unexpected characters.

I took the example in the [Node](http://rdoc.info/github/tenderlove/nokogiri/master/frames) documentation, and tried to modify it for my needs. I wanted to match a regex with the node.text value like this:

```
node.css('script:regex("[\"\']([^/s]+)[\"\']")', Class.new {
  def regex node_set, regex
    node_set.find_all { |node| node.text =~ /#{regex}/ }
  end
}.new)
```

The problem is that Node#css only accepts a string argument. #regex is basically a method call and it's argument is also a string. When I run this code, I get something like:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError (unexpected '\"' after ''(?i-mx:[\'')
```

I've tried single/double escaping the quotes, but I still get this or unexpected '['. How can I pass single/double quotes into the custom css method argument?

What I did in the meantime was to just match "script" and then loop over the nodeset with a regex matcher. Using a custom pseudo css class would be more useful though since it would be more easily reused.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Nokogiri searching for div using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649963/nokogiri-searching-for-div-using-xpath) we can't get there from here.

I usually do what you reverted to. I'll pass the results through a `.select` or `.reject` and filter out what I want. It's not the prettiest way of doing it when it'd be cooler to pass it to the selection engine, but getting it done often beats elegance.