# Nokogiri: Regex Search

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've looked at the various Nokogiri Regex threads, and this
[Nokogiri: Searching for <div> using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649963/nokogiri-searching-for-div-using-xpath)
says that nokogiri doesn't support it (in 2009).

Does Nokogiri allow regex css selectors yet?

Comment: What have you tried? Or, was your question an attempt to get us to try it for you? The linked answer is a solution to use as a fallback in case your attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the `attr^=value` and `attr$=value` and `attr*=value` selectors, yes they do work.